# AutoSwitch Two Views in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to display two views in fixed interval i.e 5 seconds or any time? So that I want to display two views from the same. How can I make it possible either via route config or via action method in the controller. I want to display the below action view in the interval of fixed time.

```
public ActionResult FlightBoardingDisplay()
{
    return View(db.tblFlightSchedules.OrderBy(m => m.Time).Where(m => m.Origin == "KATHMANDU").ToList());
}

public ActionResult FlightStatusDisplay()
{

    return View(db.tblFlightSchedules.OrderBy(m => m.Time).Where(m => m.Origin == "KATHMANDU").Where(m => m.FSId == 4).Where(m=>m.FSId ==1).Where(m=>m.FSId==3).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Sure, it is possible. Just write JS that will request for appropriate action in fixed time interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply i find the solution by inserting

```
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://192.168.5.34:8084/FlightInfo/FlightBoardingDisplay" />
```

in both the views in the head section.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this something like to call action method after some interval.The FlightBoardingDisplay View type must be [Partial View](http://techfunda.com/howto/220/create-a-partial-view)

```
<script>
  window.onload=function(){
setTimeout(function(){ callFlightStatusDisplay(); callFlightBoardingDisplay(); }, 
 3000);
 }


   function callFlightStatusDisplay()
   {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
  url: '@Url.Action("FlightStatusDisplay", "ControllerName")',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) { alert('Success'); 
     $('#DIVIDTOINSERTRESPONSE').html(data);
  },
  error: function() { alert('A error'); }
    });
 }

  function callFlightBoardingDisplay()
  {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: '@Url.Action("FlightBoardingDisplay", "ControllerName")',
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) { alert('Success'); 
     $('#DIVIDTOINSERTRESPONSE').html(data);
   },
   error: function() { alert('A error'); }
     });
   }
 </script>
```

**Controller**

```
       [HttpGet]
       public ActionResult FlightBoardingDisplay()
      {
        string date = String.Format("{0:D}", DateTime.Now.Date);
        ViewBag.Date = date;

        return PartialView(db.tblFlightSchedules.OrderBy(m => m.Time).Where(m => m.Origin == 
        "KATHMANDU").ToList());
   }

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FlightStatusDisplay()
{
    string date = String.Format("{0:D}", DateTime.Now.Date);
    ViewBag.Date = date;

    return PartialView(db.tblFlightSchedules.OrderBy(m => m.Time).Where(m => m.Origin == "KATHMANDU").Where(m => m.FSId == 4).Where(m=>m.FSId ==1).Where(m=>m.FSId==3).ToList());
}
```

Comment: As I can see, your JS by 3 seconds timer will call `callActionmethodwithpara(2);` and immediately `callActionmethodwithoutpara();`, so content on your page will blink

Comment: No I mean its up to him how he call call views

Comment: I think, that your answer **must** be "completly working", **or** "working with some reservations" (like comments `// implement this as needed`), but "not working" or "working not as expected" answers a completely unacceptable. So, if you post an answer, please, find a time to fix it.

Comment: ok I will make it more better if user disagree with current solution

Comment: just tell me have you replaced your view with partial view?

Comment: What is happening now ?

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI I get difficulty creating a partial view in this case. Is the partail view code same as other view in this case. Do both the method refers to same partial view. Please suggest how to create a partial view with this model. `@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.tblFlightSchedule>
`

Comment: yes it is same just create partial view and paste view code inside partial view except layout because we must not use layout inside partial view